# One Hot Encoding dimension - Model Compexity

Tags: deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I will explain my problem:

- I have around 50.000 samples, each of one described by a list of codes representing "events"
- The number of unique codes are around 800.
- The max number of codes that a sample could have is around 600.

I want to represent each sample using one-hot encoding. The representation should be, if we consider the operation of padding for those samples that has fewer codes, a 800x600 matrix.

Giving this new representation as input of a network, means to flatten each matrix to a vector of size 800x600 (460.000 values).

At the end the dataset should consist in 50.000 vectors of size 460.000 .

Now, I have two considerations:

- How is it possible to handle a dataset of that size?(I tried data generator to obtain the representation on-the-fly but they are really slow).
- Having a vector of size 460.000 as input for each sample, means that the complexity of my model( number of parameters to learn ) is extremely high ( around 15.000.000 in my case ) and, so, I need an huge dataset to train the model properly. Doesn't it?

Comment: You've posted this with the Python tag, so you must have some code that you've tried to run. Please include that in your question, and be specific about what you're asking for, so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you use the conventional model used in NLP?

These events can be translated as you say by embedding matrix.
Then you can represent the chains of events using LSTM (or GRU or RNN o Bilateral LSTM), the difference of using LSTM instead of a conventional network is that you use the same module repeated by N times.
So your input really is not 460,000, but internally an event A indirectly helps you learn about an event B. That's because the LSTM has a module that repeats itself for each event in the chain.

You have an example here:
https://www.kaggle.com/ngyptr/lstm-sentiment-analysis-keras

Broadly speaking what I would do would be the following (in Keras pseudo-code):

- Detect the number of total events. I generate a unique list.

  ```py
  unique_events = list (set ([event_0, ..., event_n]))
  You can perform the translation of a sequence with:
  seq_events_idx = map (unique_events.index, seq_events)
  ```
- Add the necessary pad to each sequence:

  ```py
  sequences_pad = pad_sequences (sequences, max_seq)
  ```
- Then you can directly use an embedding to carry out the transfer of the event to an associated vector of the dimension that you consider.

  ```py
  input_ = Input (shape = (max_seq,), dtype = 'int32')
  embedding = Embedding (len(unique_events),
                      dimensions,
                      input_length = max_seq,
                      trainable = True) (input_)
  ```
- Then you define the architecture of your LSTM (For example):

  ```py
  lstm = LSTM (128, input_shape = (max_seq, dimensions), dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True) (embedding)
  ```
- Add the dense and the result you want:

  ```py
  out = Dense (10, activation = 'softmax') (lstm)
  ```

I think that this type of model can help you and give better results.